# How to get the context in a widget without a Build method

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-provider

I have a Theme class that has hard coded font sizes, icon sizes, radius values, etc that I want to be dynamic so they can be responsive to different screen sizes.  I haven't been able to figure out how to use MediaQuery in my Theme class because it requires a context.  Is there a way to get context in my Theme class? Thanks for your help.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<MenuInfoProvider>(
          create: (context) => MenuInfoProvider(
            MenuName.homePage,
            menuIcon: Icons.home,
            menuText: MenuLabelString.home,
          ),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider<ThemeProvider>(
          create: (context) => ThemeProvider(),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider<UserProvider>(
            create: (context) => UserProvider()),
        Provider<Database>(
          create: (context) => FirestoreDatabase(
            uid: Auth().currentUser!.uid,
          ),
        ),
        Provider<AuthBase>(
          create: (context) => Auth(),
        ),
      ],
      builder: (context, _) {
        final themeProvider = Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context);

        return MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          title: AppConstants.improvePractice,
          theme: ThemeProvider.lightTheme,
          darkTheme: ThemeProvider.darkTheme,
          themeMode: themeProvider.currentTheme,
          initialRoute: RouteStrings.landing,
          onGenerateRoute: RouteGenerator.generateRoute,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

This is some of the code from my Theme class.  The dark theme which is excluded is similar to the light theme with different colors.

```
class ThemeProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  ThemeMode currentTheme = ThemeMode.system;

  bool get isDarkMode => currentTheme == ThemeMode.dark;

  void toggleTheme({required bool isOn}) {
    currentTheme = isOn ? ThemeMode.dark : ThemeMode.light;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  static ThemeData get lightTheme {
    return ThemeData(
      appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
        backgroundColor: AppColors.purple,
        elevation: 4.0,
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(
          color: AppColors.brandWhite.withOpacity(
            0.87,
          ),
          size: 24.0,
        ),
        toolbarTextStyle: TextStyle(
          color: AppColors.brandWhite.withOpacity(0.87),
          fontFamily: AppTextStyle.robotoSlabFont,
          fontSize: 20.0,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
          letterSpacing: 0.15,
        ),
      ),
      elevatedButtonTheme: ElevatedButtonThemeData(
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          elevation: 2.0,
          minimumSize: const Size(
            64.0,
            36.0,
          ),
          onPrimary: AppColors.brandWhite.withOpacity(
            0.87,
          ),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: 16.0,
            vertical: 8.0,
          ),
          primary: AppColors.purple,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
              8.0,
            ),
          ),
          textStyle: AppTextStyle.button,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could replace `static ThemeData get lightTheme` by a static method that takes a `BuildContext` parameter instead, Something like:

```dart
class ThemeProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  ThemeMode currentTheme = ThemeMode.system;

  bool get isDarkMode => currentTheme == ThemeMode.dark;

  void toggleTheme({required bool isOn}) {
    currentTheme = isOn ? ThemeMode.dark : ThemeMode.light;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  static ThemeData getLightTheme(BuildContext context) {
    
    // Dynamic elevation depending on device Height.
    final elevation = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height <600 ?4:6;

    return ThemeData(
      appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
        backgroundColor: AppColors.purple,
        elevation: elevation,
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(
          color: AppColors.brandWhite.withOpacity(
            0.87,
          ),
          size: 24.0,
        ),
        toolbarTextStyle: TextStyle(
          color: AppColors.brandWhite.withOpacity(0.87),
          fontFamily: AppTextStyle.robotoSlabFont,
          fontSize: 20.0,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
          letterSpacing: 0.15,
        ),
      ),
      elevatedButtonTheme: ElevatedButtonThemeData(
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          elevation: 2.0,
          minimumSize: const Size(
            64.0,
            36.0,
          ),
          onPrimary: AppColors.brandWhite.withOpacity(
            0.87,
          ),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: 16.0,
            vertical: 8.0,
          ),
          primary: AppColors.purple,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
              8.0,
            ),
          ),
          textStyle: AppTextStyle.button,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it generates an error: Getters must be declared without a parameter list

Comment: @CarletonY that's because you probably wrote `static ThemeData get lightTheme(BuildContext context)` you need to remove the `get` keyword because we're changing from a getter to a method. Check the code above. I wrote `static ThemeData getLightTheme(BuildContext context) `

Comment: Yes @BorisKayi.  I'm a beginner so I appreciate your help.  But when I do it exactly that way it creates a new error in the theme of the Main Page error: The argument type 'ThemeData Function(BuildContext)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ThemeData?'

Comment: @CarletonY Are you calling `ThemeProvider.getLightTheme(context)` in your `MaterialApp` ?

Comment: Thanks a million @BorisKayi.  I'm just trying to avoid using packages for sizing things in the app.  I still have to ask a new question on SO about dynamically sizing the font size of text in my app without a package but your answer fully answers the question above and it works perfectly.  Thanks for your persistence and help.  I learned a lot.